# Adobe Animate gotoAndPlay on mouse scroll

Tags: animation, adobe

It's been a REALLY long time since using Flash and now have to use Adobe Animate for an HTML 5 Canvas project. I created the animation, set all the actions on the timeline to stop the timeline where I need it to be but now I need to know how to play the animation again from outside of another JS file (custom.js) inside my Animate JS file (animate.js)

I've read a ton of articles and most reference the scope of **this** being the problem.

Here's how I would imagine this would work.

```
// On scroll of div
<div onscroll="myFunction()">

// inside my custom.js
  myFunction() {
    this.gotoAndPlay(2);
  };
```

Some have said to  set a var of

```
var that=this;
```

And then calling that.gotoAndPlay(2);

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Animate declares a global (window) variable exportRoot on publish that points to the root timeline.

As a demonstration, if you put this code on the root timeline:

```
 alert(exportRoot === this);
```

You should see "true".

[Thanks to ClayUUID](https://forums.adobe.com/message/10634360#10634360)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function playTimeLine () {
       //alert ("working");
       exportRoot.gotoAndPlay(30);
    }
</script>

<button onclick="playTimeLine()">PRESS</button>
```